# an inequality on matrix sign function : $A \leq \operatorname{sign} (A) \times A $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix, and $\operatorname{sign}(A)$ is the matrix sign function, which is defined as $\operatorname{sign}(A) := Z \pmatrix{-I_p & 0\cr 0 & I_q\cr}Z^{-1}$, if $A = ZJZ^{−1}$ is a Jordan canonical form arranged so that $J = \operatorname{diag}(J_1, J_2)$, where the eigenvalues of $J_1 ∈ \Bbb R^{p\times p}$ lie in the open left half-plane and those of $J_2 ∈ \Bbb R^{q\times q}$ lie in the open right half-plane.

The matrix sign function may also be calculated as $\operatorname{sign}(A) = A(A^2)^{-1/2}$.

(Obviously, the above definition holds for the matrix $A$, if $A$ has now eigenvalue on the imaginary axis.)

Is true to conclude (similar to the scalar case) that $A \leq \operatorname{sign} (A) \times A = A\times \operatorname{sign}(A) $ ?

In addition, by $A\leq B$ we mean that $A-B$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: For symmetric matrices with $n$ different eigenvectors, it seems to be trivial, Since there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$, such that $A=P^{-1}DP$, where $D=[d_{i,i}]_{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now, $\operatorname{sign}(A) \times A = P^{-1} [|d_{i,i}|]_{n\times n} P$. Hence, $\operatorname{sign}(A) \times A$ is symmetric with all non-negative eigenvalues $|d_{i,i}|$.